# Access to HOSTS file denied by search service

Tags: error, search, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I met with strange SharePoint internal error when click some links on a web site. I have tried to use SPTraceView (http://sptraceview.codeplex.com/) to dump related logs, I find the following error logs, any ideas what is wrong? I am not sure whether in my scenario, using SPTraceView is the best way to diagnose, any better ideas to diagnose?

> Application Server Job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administrator.SearchServiceInstance(xxxxxxxx-xxx GUID) Reason: access to file "C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS" is denied.

BTW: when using anonymous user, no such errors.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google seems to be returning quite a few results on this one.

Seems you might have to [manually re-configure permissions on your HOSTS file](http://ppalakollu.blogspot.com/2008/01/hosts-file-getting-deleted.html)

Comment: Whether this error could cause SharePoint internal/unknown error when I clicked some link on a Publishing portal website? Looks like this error is search related, not sure whether this error will impact when I click some web page links?

Comment: If you specify a web front end for Indexing SharePoint will insert an entry in the hosts file ensuring that the specified server is used.  In 2008 with the added security it is harder to change a host file so the extra permissions are needed.  Search results should not be impacted.

Comment: 1. "web front end for Indexing" -- do you mean content crawl source in search configuration? 2. I think the error message is dealing with search function/feature of SharePoint, but I met with this error message when I click some links to some pages in a publishing portal SharePoint web site. I do not think something wrong in search feature could impact when I click some links of a page. Any comments?